# How to import dbpedia into neo4j?

Tags: semantic-web, neo4j, dbpedia

I need to import dbpedia into neo4j.
I download the dbpedia from here: http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads37
Any idea?

Comment: You might get some help from this blog post: http://blog.acaro.org/entry/dbpedia4neo

Comment: You may find this community answer useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212015/how-to-setup-neo4j-with-dbpedia-ontop-of-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Also, I know Kenny Bastiani did some work in this area.  This seems to be a relevant project: https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-dbpedia-importer

Comment: See [this userscript](https://github.com/knutwalker/dbpedia-neo4j) posted by user @Will Tachau.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing the same thing. I found that the biggest problem for this is the indexing so the best solution is to write a java program that extracts the statements with md5 hashes into a triple file like follows:
subjectHash \t predicateHash \t objectHash \t subject \t predicate \t object \n.

In another file you will need to store the nodes (aka subjects and objects of statements):
nodeHash \t nodeValue

The code for this procedure can be downloaded from my github:
https://github.com/eschleining/DbPediaImport.git

Compile it with mvn package and it creates a jar file in target that takes the gzipped dbpedia files as arguments. If you only have the bz2 files you can transform them like follows:
`for i in *.bz2 ; do bzcat "$i" | gzip > "${i%.bz2}.gz"; done &`

Now run:
`java -jar ConcurrentDataTableWriter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar yourdbpediaFolder/*.gz`

Then you sort the newly created files manually with the sort utility of linux:
`gunzip -c nodes.gz | sort -k2 -u | gzip > nodes_unique.gz`

And the triples file:
`gunzip -c triples.gz | sort -k1,3,2 -u | gzip > triples_unique.gz`

Now you can compile the batch inserter of my repo with maven3 (mvn package) and run it in the same directory as the nodes_unique.gz and triples_unique.gz files it creates a Neo4J database directory named "DbpediaNe04J" (mind the typo "0 instead of o).

I found this to be the fastest way since it only looks up an index once for each subject/object pair in a triple.

Feel free to add datatype nodes as properties and so on. I currently have implemented each triple as a relationship between two nodes.