# what is the meaning of nodes and edges in dbpedia and neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, dbpedia

There is this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645884/how-to-import-dbpedia-into-neo4j). My problem is that I don't understand what the edges and the nodes represent in [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/)?

Can anyone explain to me that issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j is a graph database, so it models [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29). Here's a picture of a graph:

[image: graph]

The circles with numbers are the nodes. In Neo4j, they can contain any values, not just numbers. The edges are the lines between them (again, Neo4j allows arbitrary values on them). The edges represent relationships between the nodes.

In the case of DBpedia, the nodes are probably the articles and the edges are probably the links between articles. I've never heard of DBpedia before now, though, so I'm not sure on that.