# How to setup neo4j with dBpedia ontop of ruby-on-rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nlp, jruby, neo4j, dbpedia

I am trying to use `dBpedia` with `neo4j` ontop of `ruby on rails`.

Assuming I have installed [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/download/) and downloaded one of the [dBpedia datasets](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38).

**How do I import the `dbpedia` dataset into `neo4j` ?**

Comment: Another link for new neo4j.rb docs: https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/wiki

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to load dbpedia into Neo4j is to use the [dbpedia4neo](https://github.com/claudiomartella/dbpedia4neo) library. This is a Java library, but you don't need to know any Java because all you need to do is run the executable.

You could rewrite this in JRuby if you want, but regular Ruby won't work because it relies on [Blueprints](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com/), a Java library with no Ruby equivalent.

Here are the two key files, which provide the loading procedure.

1. https://github.com/oleiade/dbpedia4neo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acaro/dbpedia4neo/inserter/DBpediaLoader.java
2. https://github.com/oleiade/dbpedia4neo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acaro/dbpedia4neo/inserter/TripleHandler.java

Here is a [description of what's involved](http://blog.acaro.org/entry/dbpedia4neo).

Blueprints is translating the RDF data to a graph representation. To understand what's going on under the hood, see [Blueprints Sail Ouplementation](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Sail-Ouplementation):

After you download the dbpedia dump files, you should be able to build the [dbpedia4neo](https://github.com/claudiomartella/dbpedia4neo) Java library and run it without modifying the Java code.

First, clone the oleiade's fork of the GitHub repository and change to the `dbpedia4neo` directory:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/oleiade/dbpedia4neo.git
$ cd dbpedia4neo
```

(Oleiade's fork includes a minor Blueprints update that does `sail.initialize();` See  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/lfpNcOwZ49Y/WI91ae-UzKQJ).

Before you build it, you will need to update the `pom.xml` to use more current Blueprints versions and the current Blueprints repository (Sonatype).

To do this, open `pom.xml` and at the top of the `dependencies` section, change all of the TinkerPop Blueprints versions from `0.6` to `0.9`.

While you are in the file, add the Sonatype repository to the `repositories` section at the end of the file:

```
<repository>
  <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
  <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
```

Save the file and then build it using maven:

```
$ mvn clean install
```

This will download and install all the dependencies for you and create a jar file in the `target` directory.

To load dbpedia, use maven to run the executable:

```
$ mvn exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=org.acaro.dbpedia4neo.inserter.DBpediaLoader \
  -Dexec.args="/path/to/dbpedia-dump.nt"
```

The dbpedia dump is large so this will take a while to load.

Now that the data is loaded, you can access the graph in one of two ways:

1. Use JRuby and the Blueprints-Neo4j API directly.
2. Use regular Ruby and the [Rexster](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/) REST server, which is similar to Neo4j Server except that it supports multiple graph databases.

For an example of how to create a Rexster client, see Bulbs, a Python framework I wrote that supports both Neo4j Server and Rexster.

- http://bulbflow.com/
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tree/master/bulbs/rexster

Another approach to all this would be to process the dbpedia RDF dump file in Ruby, write out the nodes and relationships to a CSV file, and use the [Neo4j batch importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) to load it. But this will require that you manually translate the RDF data into Neo4j relationships.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it, you have two options.

1. You could either attempt to implement an approach like [this one](http://blog.acaro.org/entry/dbpedia4neo) exactly, or fork [the repo](https://github.com/claudiomartella/dbpedia4neo) behind this approach (or another like it) and extend/fix it to fit your purposes.
2. Do it yourself, from scratch. Here's the general approach:

Parse your dbpedia dataset into a format suitable for neo4j's insertion methods. There are libraries that exist like [openRDF](http://www.openrdf.org/about.jsp) that exist to process data. Unless you plan to take the time to research which would suit your needs best, the existing solution I linked above already implements this library.

Then insert the formatted data into your neo4j db. One method to accomplish this is through neo4j's [Batch Insertion](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html) component. Note this facility, as they state, is intended for initial imports (as it's not thread safe and is non-transactional, in other words, not ACID-compliant). So this really depends on your use case.

My 2 cents is that you use something already out there unless this functionality is the core of what you're developing. As it's something that will be a pain to build, and even more a pain to build something that runs efficiently.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?